# Instantiate ejb like a normal class

Tags: java, ejb

I´m developping a Java Web Application.

I have this class:

```
@Stateless
public class A {

void makeSomething();

}
```

Now I call this class in another class (I have two approaches):

```
@Stateless
public class B {

Method 1:

A a =new A();
a.makeSomething();

Method 2:

A a =new A();
a.makeSomething();

or


@EJB 
A a;

Method 1:

a.makeSomething();

Method 2:

a.makeSomething();

 }
```

My Web Application has a lot of requests. In a concurrency world what´s the best way to Instantiate class A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is using @EJB annotation. The container will inject and manage your instances. 
The container will create a pool of instances, and manage between requests, its a good practice! it not will create a new instance for each request )

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of concurrency. If it's an EJB, then it doesn't make sense to instantiate it with a constructor. If you intend to do that, make it a regular POJO.

Do you understand what it means to have an EJB as opposed to a normal POJO?

Answer (score 1):

If your class is in an EJB bean, it will be managed by the EJB container.
Though you should not create it by hand via calling it's constructor, you rather should let the container do the bean's instantiation. That's way you should inject it via `@EJB` annotations.